# Rotate linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm currently solving problem.

```
If linked list is 1,2,3,4,5 and k=2 then output should be 4,5,1,2,3
```

My approach is create a two pointer for last node and second last node.After reaching a last node connect it's next to head and make second last pointer none.Continue this process till k values.

[Excepted input and output are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNJyI.jpg)

```
class node:

def __init__ (self,data):
    self.data = data
    self.next = None

class linkedlist:

def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
    self.tail = None

def addlast(self,data):
    a = node(data)
    if self.head == None:
         self.head = a
         self.tail = a
    else:
        self.tail.next = a
        self.tail = a


def printlist(self):
    current = self.head
    while (current != None):
        print(current.data,"-->",end="")
        current = current.next
    print("NUll")

def rotatelist(self):
    k = 2 
    while k:
        current = self.head.next    
        previous = self.head
        
        while(current.next):
            current = current.next
            previous = previous.next

        current.next = self.head
        self.head= current
        previous = None
        

obj = linkedlist()
obj.addlast(1)
obj.addlast(2)
obj.addlast(3)
obj.addlast(4)
obj.addlast(5)
obj.rotatelist()
obj.printlist()
```

Comment: Did you check [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)? And what is your question anyway?

Comment: Did you notice that *rotatelist()* runs forever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four problems:

- The loop never ends because `k` is not adapted. It is more pythonic to loop over a **range**
- Setting `previous` to `None` does not do what you want. Instead `previous.next` should be set to `None`
- The function does not update `self.tail`, yet it should.
- There will be an error when the list has fewer than 2 elements -- then the code will make invalid references. You could capture this case and just return the list unchanged, as a rotation has no effect on a list with fewer than 2 elements.

Then, it is not very user-friendly to have the value of `k` hardcoded within this function. It should better be a parameter for which the caller can pass a value:

```
    def rotatelist(self, k):  # k should be parameter
        if self.head == self.tail:  # Fewer than 2 elements
            return
        for _ in range(k):  # Determine the number of iterations
            current = self.head.next
            previous = self.head
            
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
                previous = previous.next
    
            current.next = self.head
            self.head= current
            previous.next = None  # Correction
            self.tail = previous  # Update tail
        

obj = linkedlist()
obj.addlast(1)
obj.addlast(2)
obj.addlast(3)
obj.addlast(4)
obj.addlast(5)
obj.rotatelist(2)  # Pass the value of k
obj.printlist()
```

But still this method is not efficient. It needs to iterate the whole list for every rotation. Also, if `k` is much greater than the size of the list, a lot of time is wasted to rotate the list completely around, bringing it to its initial state again, and continue from there.

To make it more efficient, use `k %= n` (where `n` is the size of the list).
Temporarily make the list circular, then move the `tail` reference *n-k* steps forward, align `head`, and finally break the circle again:

```
    def size(self):
        size = 0
        current = self.head
        while current:
            size += 1
            current = current.next
        return size
    
    def rotatelist(self, k):
        if self.head == self.tail:
            return

        # Limit k to avoid useless iterations
        n = self.size()
        k %= n
        # Make list circular
        self.tail.next = self.head

        # Move tail
        for _ in range(n - k): # Determine the number of iterations
            self.tail = self.tail.next

        # Align head with tail
        self.head = self.tail.next
        # Break circle
        self.tail.next = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my solution.

```
class node:

    def __init__ (self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class linkedlist:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
    
    def addlast(self,data):
        if (self.head==None):
            self.head = self.tail = node(data)
        else:
            a = node(data)
            self.tail.next = a
            self.tail = a

    def printlist(self):
        current = self.head
        while (current != None):
            print(current.data,"-->",end="")
            current = current.next
        print("NUll")

    def rotatelist(self):
        k = 2 
        while k:
            current = self.head.next    
            previous = self.head
            
            while(current.next):
                current = current.next
                previous = previous.next
    
            current.next = self.head
            self.head= current
            previous.next = None
            k-=1
            if k<=0:
                break
        

obj = linkedlist()
obj.addlast(1)
obj.addlast(2)
obj.addlast(3)
obj.addlast(4)
obj.addlast(5)
obj.rotatelist()
obj.printlist()
```